# SQL SUM of different product groups in one query?

Tags: select, sum

I have a table with the following columns:

```
PRODUCT_ID | PRODUCT_NAME | GROUP_ID | GROUP_NAME | PRICE
```

`GROUP_ID` and `GROUP_NAME` are not UNIQUE. Can I make a selection which just returns each `GROUP_ID` with its `GROUP_NAME` and its `SUM(PRICE)`?

Or will I have to make a SELECT query for each GROUP?

For example: I have 12000 PRODUCTs which are in 14 GROUPs. My query should then only return 14 rows.

Comment: Although probably not relevant for such a basic question, you should *always* mention the DBMS you are using (Postgres, Oracle, DB2, ...)

Answer (score 0):

a `SUM` is an aggregation of data, when working with aggregations you can specify the clause `GROUP BY` to show results grouped by what you need.

```
SELECT Group_Name, 
       SUM(Price)
  FROM Table
 GROUP BY Group_Name
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT GROUP_ID, Group_Name, 
       SUM(Price)
  FROM ProductsTable
 GROUP BY GROUP_ID, Group_Name
```